# Does 26 x 1 3/8 include 26 x 1 3/8 x 1 1/4 when speaking about tyres?

Tags: tire

I know ISO standard is the way to go, but I am trying to understand what is the standard when talking about other metrics. Can I say "I have tyre 26 x 1 3/8" if my tyre is actually 26 x 1 3/8 x 1 1/4?

Comment: Are you reading the numbers on the sidewall of the tire or making a physical measurement?

Comment: What do you mean by 26 x 1 3/8 x 1 1/4? 26 is the rim size, 1 3/8 is the manf tire width claim, which will vary depending on what rim width it's mounted to and how much the maf exagerates (*cough cough* maxxis).

Comment: You're looking for logic in a ~hundred year old set of systems that involve a lot of French people.   The lack of consistency is why the ETRTO standard, now the ISO standard was created.

Answer (score 1):

Inch sizes are weird, and fractional inch sizes are even weirder. The main rules are that the "diameter" doesn't usually refer to any physical dimension of the rim or tire, and if decimal and fractional inch sizes are equivalent, they refer to different sizes. For what it's worth, it seems that there are [two different 26 x 1 3/8 standards](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/26.html), but the meaning of the last number remains unclear.